# Make an image clickable

Tags: android

I'm kind of new to this whole thing so I need some help. I have an application that creates an ImageView OnCreate. I want to make this image clickable and have it open a browser to a specific link.

How would I do this? I'm having trouble specifically with the setOnClickListener because the parameters are not accepting an OnClickListener.

I'm developing for Android 1.6

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You shoud set ImageView property clickable to true. Then set listener:

```
mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View view) {
    // do stuff
  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm. For some reason the code I was using before had invalid parameters.

Comment: android:clickable="true"

Answer (score 0):

You can subclass ImageView, if you like. Then you can override onClick in your own class. Rabas' method is probably more common though, and seen throughout Google's examples.

Comment: do you have link example what is raba's method? can't really find it in google because i don't know what it is.