# make clickable on areas of layout background

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, clickable

i use `RelativeLayout` and set background for my layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/back">
```

in background image i design some place of button, and now i want to make clickable that areas, what can i do? thnx

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible, and it is more safe tu use ImageButton or a Button with a background. See [there](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html) how to use them

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `android:background="@drawable/back"` is the background image you are speaking of you can use the [attributes of `RelativeLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) (like layout_alignLeft, layout_toRightOf/layout_toLeftOf, etc) to position `Button` objects relative to other objects in the layout. Obviously you will adjust the margin and position based on your needs.

**UPDATE**: based on the image you supplied this is a working example of how to get the buttons to line up exactly where you want them in the image.  Notice the spacing and use of the `RelativeLayout` attributes (`Button1` is positioned `133dp` from the top and `30dp` from the left.  Then `Button2` is set `toRightOf` `Button1` but pushed exactly `52dp` from `Button1`, etc).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/your_background_image">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Button1"
        android:text="Button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:text="Button2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button1"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/Button3"
        android:text="Button3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_marginTop="133dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button4"
        android:id="@+id/Button4"
        android:layout_marginTop="223dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button5"
        android:id="@+id/Button5"
        android:layout_marginTop="223dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button4"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Button6"
        android:id="@+id/Button6"
        android:layout_marginTop="223dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="52dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Button5"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Based on the background image that you supplied here are the results of the above layout:

[image: Based on the background image that you supplied here are the results of the above layout]

Comment: i tried it but my button widget not exactly sit on areas i need on background image, also its difficult for supporting multi screen :(
any other solution?

Comment: If you post your image I can show you working examples of how to achieve your goal.

Comment: this is my image that i want tu put btns ro area that shows, sry for this image: http://s5.picofile.com/file/8167607034/aaa.jpg

Comment: I updated my answer with a working example based on the image you supplied.

Comment: Did this not help you? I believe it is exactly what you were asking for.  If not then please let us know how we can help you further.  If it did help you please accept my answer.  Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

I'm think you can't make just a part of the background clickable... You'll have to make an ImageView inside that RelativeLayout and make it clickable, or make the whole layout 'clickable'.

Comment: how can i use imageview with full width background image?

Comment: Insert the imageview inside this layout, and use this params:

android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"

To make it clickable: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3443589/make-an-image-clickable)

Comment: and how can i set listener for pixels that i need?